# Django passing data from two models to a template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-views, django-urls

I have this question, pretty silly but well...I have this two models:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
CUIT = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Razon_Social = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Razon_Social

class Factura(models.Model):
TIPO_FACTURA = (
    ('A', 'A'),
    ('E', 'E')
    )
tipo_Factura = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= TIPO_FACTURA)
nombre_cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
fecha_factura = models.DateField()
IRI = models.IntegerField()
numero_De_Factura = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=140)
importe_Total= models.FloatField()
importe_sin_iva = models.FloatField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s - %s" % (unicode(self.nombre_cliente), self.numero_De_Factura)
```

I m listing the bills from each client and when the user clicks on it i want to show some information about the bill(Factura in spanish) and some information about the Client like its adress

this is my views.py:

```
def verFactura(request, id_factura):
    fact = Factura.objects.get(pk = id_factura)
    cliente = Cliente.objects.filter(factura = fact)
    template = 'verfacturas.html'
    return render_to_response(template, locals())
```

Im trying to get the information of the Client of this specific bill so i can show its information, but in the template i can´t see anything:

```
<div >
   <p>{{fact.tipo_Factura}}</p>
   <p>{{fact.nombre_cliente}}</p>
   <p>{{cliente.Direccion}}</p>
</div><!-- /.box-body -->
```

And this is my url:

> url(r'^verFactura/(\d+)$', 'apps.Administracion.views.verFactura',name = 'verFactura'),

Can anyone tell me how can i do this. Obviously i have something wrong in my code so i would appreciate the help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please format your code properly?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `cliente` is not a `Cliente` instance, but a queryset of instances. Each `factura` only has a single `cliente`, so you can do this:

```
def verFactura(request, id_factura):
    fact = Factura.objects.get(pk = id_factura)
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(factura = fact) # use `get` instead of `filter`
    template = 'verfacturas.html'

    extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['fact'] = fact
    extra_context['cliente'] = cliente

    return render_to_response(template, extra_context)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
def verFactura(request, id_factura):
    fact = Factura.objects.get(pk = id_factura)
    cliente = Cliente.objects.filter(factura = fact)
    template = 'verfacturas.html'

    extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['fact'] = fact
    extra_context['cliente'] = cliente

    return render_to_response(template, extra_context)
```

Comment: Hello. I´m using this tag in my template : <p>{{cliente.Direccion}}</p> and nothing is return. Is this the right way to get the clients adress?. I fixed my views.py with the code you suggest. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's the right way. What `local()` or `extra_context` is doing is passing a dictionary of key value pairs that you can use in your template.

Can you check to see if your cliente object is not None in the view?